# Distribution with three exponential random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Let $X \sim \text{exp}(\lambda), Y \sim \text{exp}(\mu), Z \sim
>  \exp(\gamma)$. Let U = min(X, Y), V = min(Y, Z). Compute $P(U > u, V >
>  v)$ where u, v >  $0$. (Consider two cases: one when $u < v$ and the
>   other when $ u > v$). Differentiate what you find with respect to u and v to find the joint density function (its integral will not equal 1).

$X, Y, Z$ are independent, by the way.

I found $U \sim \exp(\lambda + \mu)$ and $V \sim \exp(\mu + \gamma)$ by doing $P(U > x)$ and $P(V > y)$. But I suppose I am not so sure how to continue. Maybe please someone can help me. I am struggling because $\mu$ is a shared variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming $X,Y,Z$ are independent.

If $u \le v$ then
$$P(U > u, V > v) = P(X > u, Y > v, Z > v) = P(X>u) P(Y>v) P(Z > v) = e^{-\lambda u - \mu v - \gamma v}.$$
The other case $u \ge v$ is similar.

Comment: Hello, how can I see how to get the last equality?

Comment: @ghatrs See my edit.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. They are independent.

Comment: @ghatrs Small typo in the last step, but you have the idea.